# Outputting powershell variable as HTML table

Tags: html, powershell

I have a variable in powershell that is comprised of 19 foreach iterations of a list. Each iteration has 5 variables that I want to split up into 3 columns. I want to view it in a html table. If I just output it in text file all the information is there, but when I try to use ConvertTo-Html it either gets corrupted or lost. What am I doing wrong?

```
convertto-html $currentLog -fragment | out-file file.txt
```

Gives me:

```
<table>
</table>
```

Whereas

```
$currentLog | out-file file.txt
```

Gives me:

```
SHO: Stevens Point, WI, PING TEST: GOOD ( 1 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: N/A ( - ms)
MAD: Madison, WI, PING TEST: GOOD ( 8 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 8 ms)
DAV: Davenport, IA, PING TEST: GOOD ( 30 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 31 ms)
FRE: Freeport, IL, PING TEST: GOOD ( 16 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 16 ms)
GOL: Goldsboro, NC, PING TEST: GOOD ( 71 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 71 ms)
IRV: Irvine, CA, PING TEST: GOOD ( 73 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 73 ms)
MON: Montgomery, AL - Regional Office, PING TEST: GOOD ( 72 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 72 ms)
RIC: Richmond, VA, PING TEST: GOOD ( 52 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 53 ms)
SAL: Salem, OR, PING TEST: GOOD ( 87 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 88 ms)
SCO: Scottsdale, AZ, PING TEST: GOOD ( 95 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 95 ms)
WES: Westford, MA, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 65 ms)
MIL: Milwaukee, WI - Regional Office, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 10 ms)
EDW: Edwardsville, IL, PING TEST: GOOD ( 28 ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 36 ms)
CHA: Charlotte, NC - Regional Office, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 47 ms)
AVI: Stevens Point, WI, PING TEST: FAILED ( N/A ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 1 ms)
PLO: Plover, WI, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 1 ms)
MADG: Madison, WI, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 7 ms)
MADC: Madison, WI, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 7 ms)
MADR: Madison, WI - Regional Office, PING TEST: N/A ( - ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: GOOD ( 8 ms)
```

The code the defines the output of each line in $currentLog is:

```
$tempLine = "$($testResults.location): $($testResults.city), PING TEST: $($testResults.pingResult) ( $($testResults.pingTime) ms), PRIMARY CIRCUIT: $($testResults.circuitPrimary) ( $($testResults.circuitPrimaryTime) ms)`r`n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but this got it working.

```
$tempLine = "<tr><td>$($testResults.city)</td><td>$($testResults.pingResult) $($testResults.pingTime)</td><td>$($testResults.circuitPrimary) $($testResults.circuitPrimaryTime)</td></tr>`r`n"
$table = "<table>$currentLog</table>"
ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -body $table | out-file -FilePath $webfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the log into an array of objects, then pipe that into ConvertTo-HTML

```
$array = $array| % {
    [pscustomobject]@{ log = $_}
}
$array  | select log  | convertto-html | out-file c:\temp\file.html
```

EDIT:

if you want individual columns:

You will need to adapt it to your $testResult. You need an array of $testResult objects.
Important thing is to understand how to construct the table.

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
"@        

$testResultArray  | select location,city, pingResult, circuitPrimary, circuitPrimaryTime  | convertto-html -head $Header | out-file c:\temp\file.html
```

Comment: This gets me a little closer. I get
    <tr><th>*</th></tr>
I then get a second one with the output instead of the *. How do I separate it out into columns and rows?

Comment: That didn't work either. I posted the ugly but effective way I finally found above. Thanks for the help attempt.

Comment: It works for me, however I have generated the `$testResultArray` array which is not in the code you provided. So if you tried it `as-is`, ofc it does not work.

Comment: I was having such issues with changing $currentlog to any other format that I gave up on doing that. There is probably something else further up the code chain that was causing those problems.